# WP 8 C# physical button access

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to access Windows Phone 8 physical buttons (like volume up and down), if yes, then how?

Any tutorial or API would be helpful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only buttons you can handle are the Back button and the Camera button (if it is present and you currently have a camera preview steam open). You cannot listen for button presses on Volume, Start, or Search.

Comment: That's actually sad, there are so many possibilities, that you could use them for. Although it seems reasonable for some cases.